# combined css styles now nothin related to footer works

Tags: css

i had a previous problem with z indexing. i fixed the problem by combining head.css and foot.css into the one file. all the head styles still work, but anything related to the footer doesnt work. i basically copy and pasted the footer styles in but i dont see why that would stop the footer rules from acting the way there suppose to.

heres the code

index.php

```
<?php

  include 'view/header.php';
  include 'includes/connect.php';

  $db = new database();

  $sql = "SELECT `first_name`, `last_name` FROM `pratts_db`
          WHERE `first_name` = `clive`;";

  $result = $db->select($sql);

  if (sizeof($result) >= 1){
    echo "query successful";
    echo "<p>{$result[`first_name`]}</p>";
  }

  include 'view/footer.php';

?>
```

head.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/head.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">

    <title>Pratts of carlow </title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <header>
        <h1> Pratts of Carlow </h1>

        <div id="menubar">
          <div class="bar">
          </div>
          <div id="dos" class="bar">
          </div>
          <div class="bar">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="logos">
          <img src="images/fiat.png" alt="fiat logo">
          <img src="images/fiatpro.png" alt="fiat pro logo">
        </div>
    </header>

    <nav id="slidenav">
      <a href="#" id="exit"> x </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SALES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PARTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LOGIN</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

foot.php

```
<footer>
    <blockquote>
      <h2>ADDRESS</h2> <br>
      Pratts of Carlow <br>
      Pollerton Road <br>
      Carlow <br>
      R93 FX20
    </blockquote>
    <blockquote>
      <h2>CONTACTS</h2><br>
      Sales: <a href="mailto:sales@prattsofcarlow.ie">sales@PrattsofCarlow</a><br>
      Service: <a href="mailto:service@prattsofcarlow.ie">Service@PrattsofCarlow.ie</a><br>
      Parts: <a href="mailto:parts@prattsofcarlow.ie">Parts@PrattsofCarlow.ie</a><br>
    </blockquote>
    <blockquote>
      <h2>OPENING HOURS</h2>
      9.00am-6.00pm Monday to Friday<br>
      10.00am-1.00pm saturday
    </blockquote>
</footer>

<script src="scripts/mm.js">
</script>

<script src="scripts/exit.js">
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

head.css which contains all of the css

```
/* ****************************************************************************/
/* CSS RESET */
/* ****************************************************************************/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/******************************************************************************/
/******************************************************************************/

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(170,10,50);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(180,20,60);
}

header h1 {
  position: relative;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#menubar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 34px;
  right: 25px;
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#menubar:hover > .bar {
  background-color: rgb(180,180,180);
}

#dos {
  margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  left: -150px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  transition: left .5s ease-out;
    z-index: 1;
}

#exit {
  position: reltive;
  float: right;
  color: grey;
}

ul {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
}

nav ul li {
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(240,240,240);

}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  color: grey;
}

#logos{
  display: none
}


footer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(40,40,40);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: helvetica;
  z-index: 0;
}

footer h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(200,200,200);
}

blockquote {
  color: rgb(200,200,200);
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

blockquote a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(230,100,90);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 680px){
  footer{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }
}


/******************************************************************************/
/******************************************************************************/

@media screen and (min-width: 680px){
  #menubar {display: none;}
  #exit{display: none;}

  nav {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 550px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: 25px;
    border: none;
  }

  nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
  }

  nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 4px;
  }

  nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: white;
  }

  nav ul li a:hover {
    color: rgb(100,100,100);
  }

  #logos {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;;
    height: 76px;
    width: 200px;
  }

  #logos img {
    max-width: 76px;
  }
}
```

hopefully someone can fix this as im at my wits end

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS you got

`#logos {
    display: none
}`

It's missing a `;`, which means everything after this won't run.

Comment: i actually caught that but it didnt fix. any other ideas?

Comment: could it be because of the two media queries being the same?

Comment: I made a [codepen here](https://codepen.io/Hjorth/pen/LmPXZY) and it seems to work fine here

Comment: The media queries that are the same shouldn't change anything @busso

Comment: is it possibly because the header and footer are in different files?

Comment: I mean if the footer is rendered, the `include` must work fine. Try inspecting it and see if it gets the styles